# Why does display: flex push the following element onto a new line?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In my code, the first example works fine. The second one pushes the second element to a new line.

Why? and how to avoid it?

[**see this codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxBqdr)

```css
.one {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  width: 50%;
}
.one,
.two {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.two {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: salmon;
}
.ib {
  display: inline-block;
}
.container {
  font-size: 0;
  height: 200px;
}
.fb {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="one ib">one</div>
  <div class="two ib">two</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="one fb">one</div>
  <div class="two ib">two</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.fb{
  display: inline-flex;
 }
```

> If you use the above code you could see the difference easily.
>   
> An inline element does not start on a new line and only takes up as much width as necessary. 
>   
> But flex will start on a new line .

Answer (score 5):

You have three divs that have their `display` value set to `inline-block`. Each of these divs has a class `ib`.

You have one div with `display: flex`. This div has a class `fb`.

When you apply `display: flex` to an element it becomes a *block-level container*. As a block-level element, it takes up all available space in the line, pushing any subsequent elements to the next line.

**The way to solve this problem is to use `display: inline-flex` instead of `display: flex`.**

[Revised Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qZRYEB)

From the spec:

> [**3. Flex Containers: the `flex` and `inline-flex` display
>   values**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers)
>
> ***`flex`***
>
> This value causes an element to generate a block-level flex container
>   box.
>
> ***`inline-flex`***
>
> This value causes an element to generate an inline-level flex
>   container box.

Answer (score 0):

`flex` is actually the property you apply and enable at a container/parent level. It's not clear from your example what exactly you expect the your child divs (one and two) to do?

See this updated pen where I've removed the `ib` and `fb` classes from the children and applied `fb` to the second `container` parent:  http://codepen.io/angeliquejw/pen/qZRoLz?editors=1100

Also, CSS-Tricks has a fab breakdown that helps understand the basics of flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Updated to reflect response below:  `flex`, which you used initially,behaves more like `block` (see docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display). You want to use `display:inline-flex` : http://codepen.io/angeliquejw/pen/jqyxNz?editors=1100

Comment: hm, well the question is written in the title. your codepen is not what i want, as there is no following element that can be pushed to a new line

Comment: If you want that second element to be a flex container, try using `display:inline-flex` : http://codepen.io/angeliquejw/pen/jqyxNz?editors=1100

`flex`, which you used initially,behaves more like `block`.